# Formatting Eval into a currency, forcing en-US

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this line of code:

```
<%# Eval( "Balance", "{0:C}" )%>
```

How do I always force that to display currency in en-US regardless of what locale they have setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%# String.Format( new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:C}", Eval("Balance") %>
```

You can also set the culture for the entire page or for the entire application as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx).

Comment: Is there a way to put that into the web config to I won't have to use this long line in several different places?

Comment: I've never tried it, but this article suggests that you can. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx